# Data recovery from Apple MacBook Pro with T1 and T2 & Customer Data Migration Tool (LifeBoat)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd, recovery, migration

There is a lot of fuzz since Apple introduced non-removable SSDs in 2016. If you are spilling water or dropping the notebook it might be a problem to recover the data, as the SSDs are proprietary ([find the Ultimate Guide to Apple’s Proprietary SSDs here](https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades)).

The T1 and T2 based models differ significantly on how data is recovered (see [macrumors](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/07/22/2018-macbook-pro-lacks-data-recovery-port/)).

As i have a water-damaged 2016 MacBook Pro, i was wondering if anyone can direct me to a detailed way of how to extract the data from this model with a T1 chip.

This is the Customer Data Migration Tool connector as seen in the 2016 MacBook Pro. (Source: MacRumors)

[image: Customer Data Migration Tool connector as seen in the 2016 MacBook Pro.]

There is an Apple part #076-00236 and [it has been discussed on iFixit already](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/566823/Is+This+Tool+Really+Necessary+Apple+part+%23076-00236). Apple Gazette has a deeper investigation and concludes, that "[For A Tool That Apparently Does Not Exist, It Is Popular](https://www.applegazette.com/macbook-pro/apple-kit-customer-data-migration-tool-for-macbook-pro-2016-2018/)". There is an actual [video of someone opening this apple tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucZYTSRymYM).

It-tech.com.au has [even more info on this matter](https://www.it-tech.com.au/how-to-recover-data-from-a-dead-macbook-pro-a1707-with-touch-bar/), and more importantly, a circuit diagram for the "LifeBoat".

[image: MacBook Pro touch bar A1707 lifeboat circuit diagram]

Anyone tried this successfully at home already? Can you point me to more information and give advice: i want to know if the data extraction is feasible and doable for a person with reasonable DIY and soldering skills.

Comment: It seems we would need one question for T1 and T2 unless the tool works on both? Is that what you’re asking or just what you need for one Mac?

Comment: As far as i know there is no way yet to recover from T2, and this question is related to a T1 Apple Macbook Pro Z0UP, as outlined here https://vimeo.com/315977796

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Customer Data Migration Tool, it is actually very simple to use. It does not require any soldering or "DIY" skills. You basically just need a P5 pentalobe screw driver, andto  be able to remove the six screws that secures the the lower case.

Note that you say that you're thinking of using it on a water damaged computer. In that case you would want to use a multi-meter to first check that the power lines used by SSD power management IC (and the "Life boat" connector itself) haven't been shorted by the damage.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to "check the power lines", and especially how the "SSD power management IC" look like? I have the tool now, but the drive won't show up.

Answer (score 2):

This company sells the tool:
https://www.thebookyard.com/product.php?manufacturers_id=29&products_id=18467 Ones on eBay are more expensive, as this is a refurb.

Comment: Alternative part numbers are labelled  B076-00236, 661-05097, 923-01127, B923-00672, 923-01129, 923-01131, 923-01130 -- but actually i got one saying "620-00658" - i am not sure if the one is correct for the macbook pro (T1) which i am trying to recover. Since you were linking this - do you have more info or experience?